# Neural network (perceptron) - visualizing decision boundary (as a hyperplane) when performing binary classification

Tags: python, matplotlib, keras, neural-network, classification

I would like to visualize the decision boundary for a simple neural network with only one neuron (3 inputs, binary output). I'm extracting the weights from a Keras NN model and then attempting to draw the surface plane using matplotlib. Unfortunately, the hyperplane is not appearing between the points on the scatter plot, but instead is displaying underneath all the data points (see output image).

I am calculating the z-axis of the hyperplane using the equation
`z = (d - ax - by) / c` for a hyperplane defined as `ax + by + cz = d`

Could somebody assist me with correctly constructing and displaying a hyperplane based on the NN weights?

[image: Output:]

The goal here is to classify individuals into two groups (diabetes or no diabetes), based on 3 predictor variables using a public dataset (https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/pima-indians-diabetes-database).

```
%matplotlib notebook

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from keras import models
from keras import layers
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d

EPOCHS = 2

#Data source: https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/pima-indians-diabetes-database
ds = pd.read_csv('diabetes.csv', sep=',', header=0)

#subset and split
X = ds[['BMI', 'DiabetesPedigreeFunction', 'Glucose']]
Y = ds[['Outcome']]

#construct perceptron with 3 inputs and a single output
model = models.Sequential()
layer1 = layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', input_shape=(3,))
model.add(layer1)

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

#train perceptron
history = model.fit(x=X, y=Y, epochs=EPOCHS)

#display accuracy and loss
epochs = range(len(history.epoch))

plt.figure()
plt.plot(epochs, history.history['accuracy'])
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')

plt.figure()
plt.plot(epochs, history.history['loss'])
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Loss')

plt.show()

#extract weights and bias from model
weights = model.layers[0].get_weights()[0]
biases = model.layers[0].get_weights()[1]

w1 = weights[0][0] #a
w2 = weights[1][0] #b
w3 = weights[2][0] #c
b = biases[0]      #d

#construct hyperplane: ax + by + cz = d
a,b,c,d = w1,w2,w3,b

x_min = ds.BMI.min()
x_max = ds.BMI.max()

x = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, 100)

y_min = ds.DiabetesPedigreeFunction.min()
y_max = ds.DiabetesPedigreeFunction.max()

y = np.linspace(y_min, y_max, 100)

Xs,Ys = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Zs = (d - a*Xs - b*Ys) / c

#visualize 3d scatterplot with hyperplane
fig = plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(9, 9), dpi=100, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

ax.plot_surface(Xs, Ys, Zs, alpha=0.45)

ax.scatter(ds.BMI, ds.DiabetesPedigreeFunction, ds.Glucose, c=ds.Outcome)

ax.set_xlabel('BMI')
ax.set_ylabel('DiabetesPedigreeFunction')
ax.set_zlabel('Glucose')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Network is a Logistic Regression model so the equation of the surface is definitely z = (-b-w1*x -w2*y) / w3 . Your model needs more training. Try increasing the number of epochs (try about 500):

[image]

Since your data is not linearly separable you'll need to add hidden layers to your network in order to learn a transformation of your input that makes it linearly separable. Plotting that decision boundary is less straightforward though...

Comment: Did you produce this visualization on the same model as I presented but with just a higher number of epochs? I understand the classes will not be linearly separable but I just wanted to demonstrate how a NN works in the simplest of cases. Also, why do you have a negative bias term? I thought it should be z = (b - w1x - w2y) / w3

Comment: Yes this is the exact same code you posted with a change in the bias term in the equation and a change in the epochs. In logistic regression the separating hyperplane is exactly where the predicted probability is 1/2. This happens when σ(w1x + w2y + w3z + b) = 1/2 which only occurs when w1x + w2y + w3z + b = 0. Moving everything to one side of the equation so it can be a function of z we get: z = (-b - w1x - w2y) / w3. Hope that helps!

Comment: Really appreciate your thoughts on this. Why is the visualization you produced upside down?

Comment: In matplotlib you can move the 3d plot around with your cursor before saving it. I moved it in order to best show the surface going through the points. When you move it the axes may move too so that what you are plotting is still visible. Here if the Diabetes and BMI axes were on the bottom we would be looking at some points through that plane

Answer (score 0):

Best guess without reading all the code in detail. It looks like you applied a sigmoid activation. If you train with no activation (activation='linear'), you should get the visualization you are looking for. You may have to train longer to get convergence (assuming it can converge without an activation). If you want to keep the sigmoid, then you need to map your linear neuron through this activation (hence it won't look like a plane anymore).

EDIT:

My understanding of NNs. A dense layer from 3 to 1 and a sigmoid activation is the attempt to optimize the variables a,b,c,d in the equation:

f(x,y,z) = 1/(1+e^(-D(x,y,z)); D(x,y,z) = ax+by+cz+d

so that the binary_crossentropy (what you picked) is minimized, I will use B for the sum of the logs. Our loss equation would look something like:

L = ∑ B(y,Y)

where y is the value we want to predict, a 0 or 1 in this case, and Y is the value output by the equation above, the sum adds over all the data (or batches in a NN). Hence, this can be written like

L = ∑ B(y,f(x,y,z))

Finding the minimum of L given variables a,b,c,d can probably be calculated directly by taking partial derivatives and solving the given system of equations (This is why NN should never be used with a small set of variables (like 4), because they can be explicitly solved, so there is no point in training). Regardless of direct solving or using stocastic gradient decent to slowly move the a,b,c,d towards a minimum; in any case we end up with the optimized a,b,c,d.

a,b,c,d have be tuned to specifically produce values that when plugged into the sigmoid equation produce predicted categories that when tested in the Loss equation would give us a minimum loss.

I stand corrected though. In this case, because we have specifically a sigmoid, then setting up and solving the boundary equation, does appear to always produce a plane (did not know that). I don't think this would work with any other activation or with any NN that has more than one layer.

1/2 = 1/(1 + e^(-D(x,y,z)))
...
D(x,y,z) = 0
ax+by+cz+d = 0

So, I downloaded your data and ran your code. I don't get convergence at all; I tried various batch_sizes, loss functions, and activation functions. Nothing. Based on the picture, it seems plausible that nearly every randomized weights are going to favor moving away from the cluster than trying to find the center of it.

You probably need to transform your data first (normalize on all the axes might do the trick), or manually set your weights to something in the center, so that the training converges. Long story short, your a,b,c,d are not optimal. You could also explicitly solve the partial derivatives above and find the optimal a,b,c,d instead of trying to get a single neuron to converge. There are also explicit equations for calculating the optimal plane that separates binary data (an extension of linear regression).

Comment: My outcome is binary, hence the sigmoid activation. Also, the weighted sum of the inputs does produce a plane. However, there is something I either missed or did incorrectly when constructing the plane.

Comment: Just because you want the output to be binary, doesn't mean that you aren't mapping a linear dense layer through a exponential function. Regardless of what you want your outcome data to look like, that sigmoid must be playing a role.

Comment: You can try going to the other way. What happens if you map all your data points through a logarithm, do they line up with your plane?

Comment: The decision boundary is determined by the weighted sum of the inputs, not the output layer. It's the learned weights that perform the classification.

Comment: I am not following you, there could be something I don't understand about neural networks. Let me edit my answer, and if you could please explain what I am misunderstanding, that would greatly help me out.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this Bobby. Take a look at these two resources:
https://medium.com/@thomascountz/calculate-the-decision-boundary-of-a-single-perceptron-visualizing-linear-separability-c4d77099ef38 , https://towardsdatascience.com/applied-deep-learning-part-1-artificial-neural-networks-d7834f67a4f6 . You'll the the perception weights (not the output) is what determines separating plane.

Answer (score 0):

The decision boundary from your network is not `ax + by + cz = d` but `ax + by + cz + d = 0`.

Comment: Thanks for this @Julien. I tried changing my equation to ```Zs = ((d + a*Xs + b*Ys) / c)*(-1)``` but this did not resolve my issue. The plane still does not separate any of the points. Any further advice?